# pass string construct as function parameter

Tags: c++

look the blow code:
the second line is compile error when I use gcc? gcc show no match function to call (int, std:;string, int, int);

```
    model::FriendInfo(0, std::string(""), 0, 0);
    struct FriendInfo{
            uint32_t uid;
            std::string nick_name;
            uint16_t head_id;
            uint16_t level;
            FriendInfo(uint32_t m_uid, std::string& m_nick_name,  uint16_t m_head_id, uint16_t m_level):
                uid(m_uid), nick_name(m_nick_name), head_id(m_head_id), level(m_level){}
    }
```

Comment: You need `FriendInfo(uint32_t m_uid, const std::string& m_nick_name,  uint16_t m_head_id, uint16_t m_level):` (note the `const`).

Comment: _"but why?"_ Because you have a `rvalue` (that temporary `string()`). If you want to allow temporay values passed, you'll need a `const` reference.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the constructor parameter like

**const** std::string& m_nick_name

You may not bind temporary objects (in your case std::string("")) with non-constant references.

Also if the call of the constructor

```
model::FriendInfo(0, std::string(""), 0, 0);
```

is not assigned to some object then there is no any sense in this expression.

Comment: but I Declare std::string str = string(""), then pass str, is ok

Comment: @paul08colin  In this case str is not a temporary object.

Comment: what's the meaning of temporary object?

Comment: @paul08colin For example the statement with the call of your constructor creates an unnamed  temporary object that will be deleted after the statement execution if you will not assign it to some declared object.